# Measuring frequency response range of piezoelectric disc

Tags: matlab, frequency-spectrum, frequency-response, octave

How can I measure the frequency response range of a piezoelectric disc below.

[image: piezoelectric disc]

I don't have an oscilloscope but I do know how to program in matlab / octave I was thinking of creating a swept signal in matlab and playing it through my laptop or tablet and playing it through the disc.  But how do I measure the frequency response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that it is rather impossible without a proper hardware. Sweep sine is ok as a general method, but you would either need:

- Reference transducer with known (preferably) linear frequency response. Then you can find the difference between those two.
- Signal actuator with known frequency response, and then you can also find the difference between recorded signal and what it should be.

In any other case you will only measure the convolution of actuator response and response of piezoelectric element.

You should also understand that this disc is meant to be used as a contact device, not for recording of sound waves. There is a huge difference between those two signals recorded.

Lastly you can try to search for frequency characteristic of known model (presumably measured by someone). I did similar work back in time, but we used different type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with sound. You just need a flat response speaker which is very common in music production studios or even in houses where a DJ resides. These speakers ensure a flat response, that is, they do not deviate +/3dbs from the 100% flat reference. You also have to know that these speakers are usually flat in the 50-20Khz range more or less. You really do not need to know the exact values ​​that the sensor can give you, but the differences between the different frequencies measured taking into account the "flat" voltage that the sensor should offer. This can help you get an objective perspective on the sensor's frequency response, at least in the speaker's frequency range. You just have to place the sensor in a position close to the speaker and, without moving it a millimeter, trigger tones or sine waves at the frequency you want and measure the sensor's reaction with a voltmeter. Write down the results and draw the curve of its frequency response. There are "shakers" that, basically, are a vibrator at a certain frequency and that are used to verify industrial vibration sensors but they are expensive equipment and it is expensive to hire an engineering company to offer you this service. Tip: Try to stay quiet when you measure. :-)